# What does it mean in Visual Studio debugger value "{ }"?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I have in my Visual Studio 2008 .NET C# project one property observed and debugger shows open and immediately closed curly brackets "{}". 
I believe it is uninitialized (I)List, but why it does not shows "null" or "unitialized". What does "{}" it means ?

br,
Milan.

Comment: Looks like a list with nothing inside to me.

Comment: I agree with Will Eddins, it looks like an empty list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely reason is that the type of the value in question overrides the `.ToString()` method and returns an empty string.  This will cause the display to be {} as the C# EE wraps the return of .ToString inside of {}'s

Answer (score 2):

This can indicate a value of `System.DBNull`

You can check against it like this:

```
                    foreach (var val in datarow.ItemArray)
                    {
                        if (val == DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            var item = val;
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the value shown in the debugger you can control it with the [DebuggerDisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx).  You could also override the `.ToString()` method instead.  But this could affect other areas of your applications.