# What do the curly brackets in Visual Studio debugger mean?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've seen this question but I think mine is different: [What does it mean in Visual Studio debugger value "{ }"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071611/what-does-it-mean-in-visual-studio-debugger-value)

I don't see just curly brackets, instead I think I see a type.  Anyways this is what I see:

[image]

For `res`, I see {System.Net.Http.StreamContent}. Instead, what I would expect/hope to see is something like "[content here]". This is how I am calling it:

`var res = await client.PostAsync(endpoint, content);`
Does anyone know why it displays the type, and how to fix this? thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using the Debugger, it uses the ToString() method on whatever object you're looking at.  So if you debug this code:

```
public void Debugging()
{
    MyClass fancyVariable = new MyClass();
    // debugging fancyVariable here
}
public class MyClass
{
    public int val;
}
```

... debugging that 'fancyVariable' will just say: {Namespace.MyClass}

But!  If you change it to:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int val;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Value=" + this.val;
    }
}
```

... then debugging will say "Value=0" when you're 'watch'ing that variable.

So why is your debugging using {ClassName}?  Because a lot of classes are hard to represent well with ToString() - either because there's not an easy way of summarizing the data in a quick little blurb, or because *getting* that information would cause problems (either because it might take too long or because it'd cause functional problems.)  StreamContent has pretty much all those problems - it's not easy to represent with a blurb, it might take a bit of time to pull data from the stream, and it might cause functional problems to pull from the stream.  So it simply has a ToString() that returns its class name.

If you're looking to have some fun, poke around with some of the built-in .NET classes and take a look at which ones present a blurb in the ToString() and which ones do {Something.ClassName}

(It's also a lesson on why you should always at least contemplate overriding the ToString() method for any class you write: to make debugging problems with the class easier.)

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be intentional.

You are definitely seeing the type. The client.PostAsync method has Content of type System.Net.Http.HttpContent, specifically System.Net.Http.StreamContent.

Had the Content type been a string, then you might see something like "Content string"

In order to read the contents, you'll have to do something like this:

```
var contents = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Hope this helps!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138242(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 1):

> For res, I see {System.Net.Http.StreamContent}. Instead, what I would expect/hope to see is something like "[content here]".

But res is not content, it is a `System.Net.Http.StreamContent` object, thus it's tell you want it is.  **You cannot change how these classes work**.  The value you are looking for is contained in the Content, but thats a stream, which doesn't always have a known state, so you can't really look at it's value either.

Comment: Ah, right so Res is set to be a stream as determined by the `HttpClient` class. But because I `await` it doesn't that mean it should wait for the results/content to come back?

Comment: await has nothing to do with it.  Streams aren't necessarily known at any point in time, because of the underlying framework.  But regardless, if you did this with your own class, it would show your own class unless you used the [DebuggerDisplayAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.1)

Comment: @ErikPhilips I believe overriding ToString() will cause a new value to be shown too.

Comment: Thanks Erik I see what you are saying now, especially with all the other answers. You are saying that it would show {my_class_name} if I somehow implemented the `StreamContent` class. The general rule for when something will be shown by its object type as opposed to its value in the debugger is whatever its toString() method says. I upvoted you and everyone else who answered but think Kevin's was the most clear.